# Spring Preauthorized works but HTTPSecurity possibly being ignored?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have security setup in my Spring Boot application using OpenId and Spring Boot Security.

By accident I forgot to add a role type to my `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('...)")` tag and tried to make a call as a `USER` and was denied (403), but I do have the hasAnyRole stated in my securityConfig file. Once I added the role to the preAuth tag it worked, but I'm wondering if that is expected behavior? Or am I doing something wrong in the security config file?

I'm using the following Spring Boot Security Settings

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Web Security File

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private JdbcOidcBearerTokenFilter filter;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(@Value("${security.oauth2.client.wellKnownUrl}") String wellKnown
            , @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}") String clientId
            , @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}") String clientSecret
            , EaUserService usersService, LoginService loginService) {

        OidcService oidcService = new OidcService(wellKnown, clientId, clientSecret);
        this.filter = new JdbcOidcBearerTokenFilter(oidcService, usersService, loginService, "Authorization");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/error", "/403.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(this.filter, OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/static/**").permitAll()   
                .antMatchers("/api/enforcementactions/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","DEVELOPER","USER")
    }
}
```

Controller with PreAuth Tags
Here I forgot to add 'USER' to the tag at first and was denied access, but shouldn't the settings above in the HttpSecurity Method have taken care of it?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','DEVELOPER','USER')")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/enforcementactions")
public class EnforcementActionsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EnforcementActionsService service;

    @GetMapping("/getallactions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllEnforcementActions() {
        ... do stuff here and return data
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule in the `HttpSecurity` configuration was not ignored, it was simply evaluated before the rule in `@PreAuthorize`.

A call to `/api/enforcementactions` from a user with the role `USER` will first go through the Spring Security filter chain.
This is where the rule from `HttpSecurity` will be examined.
It states that if a user has any of the following roles `"ADMIN"`, `"DEVELOPER"` or `"USER"` then they may proceed.
The user in question has the role `"USER"` so the request continues down the filter chain.

Once the request has gone through the filter chain, then the rule in `@PreAuthorize` will be checked, right before the Controller method is called.
This rule states that only users with the roles `"ADMIN"` and `"DEVELOPER"` can access this method, and our user only has the role `"USER"` so their request is rejected at this point.

It may appear that the `@PreAuthorize` rule is the only one being considered, but that is because it is more specific.
If the rule in `HttpSecurity` was more specific then the request would be reject in the filter chain before it reached `@PreAuthorize`.